# Manually Built Qt incorrect configuration Paths

Tags: qt, ubuntu, static-linking

My machine use Ubuntu OS.
I built Qt 5.5.1 manually against static linking. Configuring the built, specified a path to install to:

```
$ ./configure -static -prefix /home/myname/qt_src/installed/
```

Then I moved the built stuff to another Ubuntu machine and tried call qmake from a shell:

```
$ qmake CONFIG+=release CONFIG-=debug /home/othername/project/q_panorama.pro -r -spec linux-g++
```

But I stucked with error

```
Could not find qmake configuration file linux-g++
```

Trying to fix it, I discovered that qmake's QTDIR (is it?) is incorrect:

```
$ qmake -v
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.1 in /home/myname/qt_src/installed/
```

Okay. Try to change special var with `qmake -set` option (here consider only one of vars - QT_INSTALL_PREFIX, - for simplicity). First, check it's consistency:

```
$ qmake -query QT_INSTALL_PREFIX
/home/myname/qt_src/installed/
```

Perform:

```
$ qmake -set QT_INSTALL_PREFIX "/home/othername/qt_static/"
```

Check again:

```
$ qmake -query QT_INSTALL_PREFIX
/home/myname/qt_src/installed/
```

Why the variable does not modify?

How can I make Manually Built static version of Qt work? Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

Did not find the way to resolve the issue, and thus decided to act with brute force:

1. Created a user `othername` in my machine;
2. Run full build cycle for the path desired (under the user created).
3. Copied the built stuff to the target machine
4. PROFIT.